# what's the complement to accessories?

Tags: terminology, generic-term, computing

The mouse and keyboard are the accessories of a computer, and the charger and headphone are the accessories of a phone.

My question is: what is the generic term for a computer/phone that's the complement of accessories (i.e. the main part of a system)?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a term applicable only to electronic gadgetry, or a more general term that could describe say, the clothing to which jewelry and handbags are accessories, or the sailboat to which a spinnaker and hiking harness are accessories?  Further, the single-word-request tag requires that you provide a sample sentence where the word would be used.

Comment: @cobaltduck right now I'm looking for the term for an electronic system, but it would be better if the term is more general. I have removed the single-word-request tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Device* is one commonly-used generic term you could use.

One could say:

i. the screen of your device
ii. the plug to your device
iii. the charger to your device

But, of course, context would need to tell the reader whether your "device" is a phone, a computer, or a whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there exists a word that will be instantly understood to mean what you describe.  However, there is a group of words that can describe the role of the thing which the accessories go with.  You use one of those in your question- the [main](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/main) part.  Other possibilities are [core](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/core) and [principal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principal).  (all links are to M-W)

As examples, the computer forms the *core* of a desktop set-up, along with the monitor, mouse, and keyboard.  A nice suit is the *principal* element of a professional outfit, augmented by jewelry and neck-wear.  For a good day of sailing, the *main* concern is the fitness of the hull, etc.